# How to know cell location name using cell id and lac in Android?

Tags: android

i just want to find the location name, and cell name using cell tower id and LAC in Android.  Also how to redirect the incoming call to our own application from where the caller number is shown to user like the normal calling information?  [as of now when some one calls someone the mobile number is shown,]  I want to show the receiver of the call the location of the caller with his/her mobile number.

Answer (score 0):

did you try with this apis `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/GsmCellLocation.html` ?  & also there is one app in google store "CellID Info - Android Apps on Google Play" you can try with that.